# How can I save the last command to a file?

Tags: bash, shell, command-history

When I am running my analyses using the bash shell, I often want to save the commands I've used that gave me good results to a file in the same directory (my "LOGBOOK", as its called) so that I can check what I did to get those results. So far this has meant me either copy.pasting the command from the terminal or pressing "up" modifying the command to an `echo"my command" >> LOGBOOK`, or other similar antics.

I found there was a `history` tool the other day, but I can't find a way of using it to get the previously executed command so that I can do something like `getlast >> LOGBOOK`.

Is there a nice easy way to do this. Alternatively, how do others deal with saving the commands for results they have?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

If you are using `bash`, you can use the `fc` command to display your history in the way you want:

```
fc -ln -1
```

That will print out your last command. `-l` means list, `-n` means not to prefix lines with command numbers and `-1` says to show just the last command. If the whitespace at the start of the line (only the first line on multi-line commands) is bothersome, you can get rid of that easily enough with `sed`. Make that into a shell function, and you have a solution as requested (`getlast >> LOGBOOK`):

```
getlast() {
    fc -ln "$1" "$1" | sed '1s/^[[:space:]]*//'
}
```

That should function as you have asked in your question.

I have added a slight variation by adding `"$1" "$1"` to the `fc` command. This will allow you to say, for example, `getlast mycommand` to print out the last command line invoking `mycommand`, so if you forgot to save before running another command, you can still easily save the last instance of a command. If you do not pass an argument to `getlast` (i.e. invoke `fc` as `fc -ln "" ""`, it prints out just the last command only).

[Note: Answer edited to account for @Bram's comment and the issue mentioned in @glenn jackman's answer.]

Comment: The first form `fc -lnr | head -n 1` can be abbreviated to `fc -lnr -1`.

Comment: @Bram: Good stuff. I was using `help fc` for my documentation. The bash man page has more details, including this use of negative indices. Eliminating `head` is good because the one command left is built-in so now there's no fork/exec.

Comment: I wonder why the command is called `fc`...

Comment: It stands for "fix command".  http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-History-Builtins

Answer (score 10):

One problem with @camh's answer is if you have a command that spans multiple lines, it only shows the first line:

```
$ echo "one
> two
> three"
one
two
three

$ fc -lnr | head -1
         echo "one
```

Try this:

```
$ alias getlast='fc -nl $((HISTCMD - 1))'

$ echo "one
> two
> three"
one
two
three

$ getlast
         echo "one
two
three"
```

Comment: enabling `cmdhist` will fix that: "If set, bash attempts to save all lines of a  multiple-line  command  in  the same history entry.  This allows easy re-editing of multi-line commands."

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the up arrow, you can use `"!!"` to refer to the previous command.

e.g.

```
$ some -long --command --difficulty="very hard to remember"
$ echo "!!" >> LOGBOOK
```

note: this does not quote the literal text

Comment: That will not capture the literal command. If there are any shell metacharacters, they will be evaluated and substituted. Pipelines will also break: `ls | less` -> `echo !! >> LOGBOOK` -> `echo ls | less >> LOGBOOK`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with the following command if you are using bash shell:

```
$> history -a LOGBOOK
```

This will append all your commands from current session to that file, you can also add an alias on your ~/.bashrc file to do this with a single command:

```
$> alias getlast="history -a LOGBOOK"
```

Comment: But you're missing the more important requirement that I only save the commands that worked and got the results I have. I don't want to save _all_ the recent commands I've done, just select ones after I've used them. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score -2):

```
fc -l | awk 'FNR == 15 {print $2}' > /tmp/last_command
```

I capture the last command with awk from fc -l output and print it to /tmp/last_command

Comment: (1) Why 15? (2) ```{print $2}``` is wrong.